# Duplicate socialite callbacks from facebook & google

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-5.6

i've implemeted socialite login to my laravel 5.6 application and get duplicate callbacks from google and facebook. Twitter works right with a single callback request.

The redirect and callback functions are standard functions like the examples in the documentation.

Redirect function:

```
public function redirectToGoogle() {
    return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
}
```

Callback function:

```
public function callbackFromGoogle() {
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
    $this->handleCallback($user );
}
```

Logfile:

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2018:19:57:49 +0100] "GET /login/facebook HTTP/1.0" 302 2649 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2018:19:57:50 +0100] "GET /login/facebook/callback?code=... HTTP/1.0" 200 1096 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36                        "
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Mar/2018:19:57:50 +0100] "GET /login/facebook/callback?code=... HTTP/1.0" 200 1100 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.162 Safari/537.36                        "
```

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you maybe post the whole callback URL that is called by Facebook? Is the code the same or are they different?

Comment: The urls just include the auth tokens. Sometimes they are equal and sometimes they are different.